# how to make a clr-datagrid selectable (single/multi) dynamically?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Here's an outline of a component called "my-clr-list" that uses clarity datagrid like:

```
<clr-datagrid>
   bunch of clr-dg-column definitions...
   <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users$ | async">
      <clr-dg-action-overflow>
          bunch of buttons...
       <\clr-dg-action-overflow>
       bunch of <clr-dg-cell> ...
   </clr-dg-row>
   <footer>
</clr-datagrid>
```

I want to be able to pass a boolean input to this component based on which I can dynamically(load time) add

```
[(clrDgSingleSelected)]="selectedUser"
[clDgRowSelection]="true"
```

to the clr-datagrid.

I am able to achieve this by duplicating the clr-datagrid using *ngIf, but is there another way to add the options dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use two different datagrids, but you could save the internals of the datagrid inside of an ng-template and reuse it inside each datagrid. Alternatively, you could also componentize some of the internals of the datagrid (careful, as this could break projection).